# Custom domain not reflecting individual links

Tags: dns, hyperlink, blogs, blogger, cname

I have linked a custom domain name through GoDaddy to my Blogger blog. It all works fine. For example, my domain name is (example, not the real site) www.myblog.com. My blogger site is (again, example, not the real site) www.myblog.blogspot.com. 
It all looks the same on the home page. The issue comes when I click on a specific post. For instance the post "Great Cake" under the blogger address shows up www.myblog.blogspot.com/greatcake. However, the domain name (the one I want to use) still only shows up as www.myblog.com, no matter what page I am on. Because of that, I cannot share links for individual pages, only for the whole blog itself.
I hope that made sense. I'm looking for a way to have the domain name (that is forwarded with masking through GoDaddy) also reflect individual posts and pages with an individual web address.
Can anyone explain how I could do that? Because I'm not sure how to word the question, I'm having no luck trying to find an answer on the internet, though I find many blogs that do what I want mine to do and are also powered by Blogger. Please help!

Comment: can you share your blog url?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have done the basic GoDaddy setup (I'm using Namecheap), but you may not have completed the blogger setup. Instructions are here https://support.google.com/blogger/troubleshooter/1233381?hl=en#ts=1734115

Answer (score 0):

New Blogger no longer provides custom domain. Read how to set up the custom domain in 30 just minutes, if that is the case [link](http://www.morldtechgossips.com/2013/11/how-to-get-and-install-custom-domain_7.html)